# Use a fallback font when using the Google Fonts CDN

Tags: css

Can I use web fonts and Google Fonts API both (if user has the google fonts CDN blocked)? Namely,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SourceCodePro-Bold";
    src: url(../fonts/SourceCodePro-Bold.ttf);
}

h1{ font-family: "SourceCodePro-Bold";}
```

and

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Have you tried that? Did it work? Sounds like you can, why not?

Answer (score 3):

Same as any font-family fallback. Use a comma separated list of the fonts for `font-family`.

Make sure your local fonts don't have the same name as the Google fonts.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/...' />

<style type='text/css'>
* {
    font-family: 'Google Font', 'back up local', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```